# How can I use Rx Swift PublishRelay with no type just for onCompleted() event?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have this view model in my code:

```
import RxSwift

protocol ViewModelInput {
    func buttonTouched()
}

protocol ViewModelOutput {
    var done : PublishRelay<Bool> { get set }
}

protocol ViewModelType {
    var inputs: ViewModelInput { get }
    var outputs: ViewModelOutput { get }
}

public final class ViewModel: ViewModelInput, ViewModelOutput, ViewModelType {

    var inputs: ViewModelInput { return self }
    var outputs: ViewModelOutput { return self }

    internal var done = PublishRelay<Bool>.init()

    init() {}

    func buttonTouched() {
        self.outputs.done.accept(true)
    }
}
```

And I'm using it's "output" like this:

```
// Somewhere else in my app
        viewModel.outputs.done
        .asObservable()
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
            // whatever
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

To be honest I don't need that `Boolean` value with `PublishRelay`. I don't even need `onNext()` event. All I need is to notify my coordinator (part of app that uses this view model) about `onCompleted()`. However there is still some `<Bool>` generic type added to my output. I don't need any of that. Is there any cleaner way to achieve that?

I though about traits like `Completable` but as far as I understand I need to emit completed-event inside `create()` method or use `Completable.empty()`. Or maybe I don't understand traits that good, I don't know.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rx has always been zero or more values of the specified type. If you're producing zero elements then the type is less important. In .NET there is a special type `Unit` for the void type. I imaging that RxSwift has something the same. Use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't done any RxSwift in a while, but have you tried making the type `PublishRelay<Void>`? Once you do that you can just pass `()` to `outputs.done.accept(())` in your `buttonTouched()` method and not have to worry about passing arbitrary information that isn't needed

Comment: Yeah, I don't like that ```<Void>``` at all but this seems to be the only one solution :)

Comment: so essentially it can also mean
done = PublishRelay<()>() right ?

Comment: @AmitSingh yes, it should be able to be done that way as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think @Steven0351 is right with the < Void> approach. Just 2 little things:

1. It should also work by terminating the subject instead of emitting a Void value. It looks cleaner in the subscription as well.
2. I guess you are subscribing your outputs.done subject in the UI. In that case you might want to use *Drivers*. That way there's no need to specify observation on main scheduler (among other *Drivers* advantages).

**ViewModel**

```
internal var done = PublishRelay<Void>.init()

func buttonTouched() {
    self.outputs.done.onCompleted()
}
```

**ViewController**

```
viewModel.outputs.done
    .asDriver()
    .drive(onCompleted: { [weak self] in
        // whatever
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```